# WPF ControlTemplate Datatrigger in application.xaml

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, datatrigger

Hopefully someone can help me out; I have created a Style for a `ContentControl`. This is globally done in `application.xaml`. The `ContentControl` is used on several `usercontrols`. In the style of the control I have created a Grid named `"SizeInfo"` that is visible on `MouseHover`. Now i want add a `Datatrigger` that change the visibility of the grid `"SizeInfo"`. This i can't figure out how to do it. This is the code so far:

```
<Grid>    
   .....................
<Grid x:Name="sizeInfo" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
   .....................
</Grid>
<ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
</Grid>
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Content.MoveOrResizeControls, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="sizeInfo" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
       </DataTrigger>                           
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
             <Setter TargetName="sizeInfo" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
       </Trigger>
       <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
              <Setter TargetName="sizeInfo" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
       </Trigger>
 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
```

VB

```
''' <summary>
''' Get or Set wether the user can resize and move controls. Default off
''' </summary>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Property MoveOrResizeControls As Boolean = False
```

Comment: I guess DataTrigger should have higher priority so move it below triggers, otherwise it will be always overwritten by IsMouseOver property.

Comment: also `MoveOrResizeControls` should be a dependency property

Comment: Ah i see i have to change it to a dependency property, but how can i set this is up in a class that has nog UI element? (it's a Class that holds settings for the whole application that is passed through in de New constructor of an Usercontrol that needs it)